# How do you add a space on top of a comment in a bash script

Tags: bash, sed

Given a script like this

```
# I love this comment
echo "Code code code"
# I love this comment more
echo "More code, more code"
```

I want to automatically change it to

```
# I love this comment
echo "Code code code"

# I love this comment more
echo "More code, more code"
```

How do I accomplish that

Comment: *I love this comment more* :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
sed '2,$ s/^#/\n#/'
```

It will add a new line in front of every `#` on the beginning of a line, except of the first line.

Comment: or `'s/^\s*#/\n&/'` if the comments can be indented

Comment: +1 for *"beginning of a line, except of the first line"*.  You wouldn't want to insert a blank line in front of your `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*#/ && NR>1 {$0=RS$0}1' file
# I love this comment
echo "Code code code"

# I love this comment more
echo "More code, more code"
```

It adds a blank line before every line starting with `#` except the first line.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma No more `blink` :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1b;/^#/i\\' file
```